# Uninstall only the lastest update of an android app

Tags: android, webview, updates

I want to uninstall the lastest (only the lastest) update of the android webview, because it causes some my apps crashes on my device.

But from Settings->App->All->Android WebView I'm only able to uninstall all the updates of that app...

How can I uninstall only the last?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This question is not about programming. This might be the reason why if don't find any help here. Maybe this is the right place [http://android.stackexchange.com/](http://android.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It´s not possible to uninstall only the latest update of an app. You can find the apk file of the last version on [APK Mirror Android Web View](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/android-system-webview/)

However, this is the false forum for this question.